# error: expected color but got (raw string) color/gray

Tags: android, android-studio, styles, android-studio-3.0

I have switched to android studio 3. after many problem that I fixed, I got this error:

color/colorPrimary but i go this error:Error:(87, 5) error: expected color but got (raw string) color/gray

[image]

Comment: I had this error even when problem was not in the color. I had `<item name="android:background">null</item>` without the @ sign.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You forgot to add  **`@`**  before `color/colorPrimary`

change it  like **`@color/colorPrimary`**

**sample code**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
```

Comment: Looks like perfect answer.

Comment: according to this page https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#at_symbol migrating to Android Studio 3 requires to remove them. I guess that's were OP is referring to.

Comment: @dhesse remove what  ? can you explain? i have same issue

Answer (score 0):

Color value should be a `hex` color code like `#A5D3F4` OR a color reference with `@` sign, like  `@color/colorPrimary`. before use these reference, you must create resources like `res/values/color.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#6200EE</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#3700B3</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#03DAC5</color>
    <color name="LabelColor_text_50">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="ValueColor_text_50">#333322</color>
    <color name="LabelColor_bg_50">#A5D3F4</color>
    <color name="ValueColor_bg_50">#E6EEF4</color>
</resources>
```

And use these name as `<item name="someName">@color/LabelColor_text_50</item>`